# Why calls to JOptionPane are not done on EDT automatically?

Tags: java, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I had a Problem with a call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` why this call was not done on the Event-Dispatch-Thread. The fix is to execute it on the EDT, in this way:

```
if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
  try{
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
      }
    });
  }catch(...){...}
}else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
}
```

and here my question.... why is this check not automatically done by every method of the JOptionPane class?

Comment: The entire Swing API works this way. Why? Probably for speed and performance. The Swing API just assumes you'll do the right thing or suffer the consequences. There are ways to work around it, using a custom repaint manager for example, to detect operations which occur off the EDT, which I use in development, but that's no guarantee that it will catch all violations. SWT and JavaFX for example actively throw exceptions if your violate the single thread rule, but they have the benefit of been designed when hardware was a little more robust and the performance hit wasn't so great to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is necessary in every case. While we know that swing is not generally thread-safe, it is thread-safe while access is localized to the method creating the swing components, and before it is shown on the screen, exposing it to the UI thread

Comment: *"t is thread-safe while access is localized to the method creating the swing components, and before it is shown on the screen"* - That's not actually guaranteed. It's possible for one or more components to generate events which might effect other components during the initialization process. As a general thumb, do creating and modification on the EDT, it's just safer or round

Comment: So in the case we're talking about here, are you saying that calling JOptionPane.showXXXDialog(...) could run into threading issues? I honestly don't see how in this case it could ever happen.

Comment: There is still the possibility, given that the API could create not just the dialog but also the label, panels and buttons, but if you're passing in a more complex object (a custom component), then you run into a more greater possibility.  The fact is, it "could" happen and what's worse, it could happen differently on different platforms. The fact remains that there is a possibility for components to generate events before they are shown, which could effect other components.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would call these contrived situations... Exposing components being displayed in a JOptionPane to other threads? I mean... Look, we're in agreement here about Swing and the need to use the UI thread heavily. What I'm saying is that there are plenty of common situations when you can use JOptionPane.showXXX without having to do this on the UI thread because you can be certain no other threads can reach it. Agree?

Comment: No, primarily because you now have at two threads which could be interacting with the option pane. My point is not a it the option pane, it's about your assumption generally. Given the fact the the option pane also takes control over the event processing from the EDT, adds another level of complexity and concern to the or home. The op them selves expressed that they had an issue by doing what you're suggesting (using option pane from outside the EDT) would seem to contracting your claims.

Comment: The question isn't if it can be done or not, but why the API doesn't support auto synchronisation to the EDT (or throws and error)